# Running a federated RabbitMQ on port 80

Tags: http, webserver, rabbitmq, amqp

Our client has a requirement that a web server can only have port 80 and 443 open, both public and internal facing, but our application would benefit from using queuing on the inside.

Is it possible to run RabbitMQ over port 80?

**Update**

The setup is as follows.

We have a public facing API server which calls various back end systems.

In between the API server and the back end servers there is another layer which in most cases just works like a proxy.

Some of the back end systems, as well as the proxy layer, go up and down intermittently.

What I would like to do is have a queue on the API server, a queue in the proxy layer and a queue in the back end layer.

These queues would be federated so that a messages placed on the queue on the API server would be forwarded all the way down to the back end servers (queuing is needed for inserts and updates only).

Comment: No, this is not possible, nor should you want to from a security standpoint.

Comment: How is this bad from a security standpoint? I was thinking it would be possible to route message in IIS based on protocol, i.e. AMPQ over port 80 would be routed to another port where Rabbit is listening?

Comment: For one, non-http traffic over port 80 will often be blocked by firewalls. RMQ is not designed to be public-facing. You should ensure there is a web service layer to intercept potential poison pill messages and other attempts at malfeasance. Your client's security requirements are probably (hopefully) more extensive than simply stipulating ports.

Comment: You are probably right that non-http traffic is blocked but doesn't the RabbitMQ Stomp work over http?

Comment: Yes but it is using HTML. I just don't think it is a good idea unless all messaging end points are public facing and/or secured in some other way (expensive).

Comment: In your updated question, you do not describe the location of an HTTP-based implementation of RabbitMQ. Are you planning to expose the API endpoints via message queues, or does the API act as an intermediate layer? As-is, I believe this question is too broad and is best addressed on Programmers or some other stack exchange site.

Answer (score 1):

One way is using Web-Stomp plugin and Sock.js, using nginx as proxy.
Another way - node.js callback for some sending messages, handling events and create messages with node.js.
Server side works with RabbitMQ by localhost connect with default port.

Third way is using subdomain with another IP adress.

Comment: Would any of these approaches work with federated exchanges/queues?

Comment: You planning using it from exactly client-side? It is program or website?